# Slideshow made from HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a student learning basic HTML/Javascript, and for homework I was assigned to make a slideshow from HTML/Javascript. I just learned about arrays, functions, and variables, so I'm quite new to everything.

So for this slideshow assignment, I have to put two buttons that start/stop the slideshow, as well as two buttons that go to the next or previous photo of the slideshow, and when I press the next/previous buttons, it should go to the next/previous slide and stop the slideshow as well.

For my slideshow, I used arrays to show the photos, captions, and caption titiles based upon the slide number, represented as the variable "i".

But I've run into some problems with my slide show. I'll explain after I paste my code right here. I've used the  tag so I don't have an external Javascript File.

Please don't worry about the image sources as I've got that all sorted out, and also, there's no need to worry about that CSS file either.

Here is my code:

```css
img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
}

#captiontitle {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#caption {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HW: Slideshow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Slideshow</h1>
    <h3 align="center">(Please note that the time transition between slides is one second. Thank you!)</h3>

    <img name="banner" width="800" height="400" class="center">
    <h1 id="captiontitle" align="center"></h1>
    <figcaption id="caption" align="center"></figcaption>

    <button id="start" onclick="transition()">Start</button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stoptransition()">Stop</button>
    <button id="next" onclick="nextphoto()">Next Photo</button>
    <button id="previous" onclick="previousphoto()">Previous Photo</button>

    <p id="firsti"></p>
    <p id="ivalue"></p>
    <p id="timevalue"></p>


    <script>
    //Images//
    var images = [];
    var i = 0;
    var time = 1000;
    images[0] = "img0.jpg";
    images[1] = "img1.jpg";
    images[2] = "img2.jpg";
    images[3] = "img3.jpg";
    images[4] = "img4.jpg";
    images[5] = "img5.jpg";

    var captitle = [];
    captitle[0] = "Image 0"
    captitle[1] = "Image 1"
    captitle[2] = "Image 2"
    captitle[3] = "Image 3"
    captitle[4] = "Image 4"
    captitle[5] = "Image 5"

    var cap = [];
    cap[0] = "This is the description of Image 0."
    cap[1] = "This is the description of Image 1."
    cap[2] = "This is the description of Image 2."
    cap[3] = "This is the description of Image 3."
    cap[4] = "This is the description of Image 4."
    cap[5] = "This is the description of Image 5."

    document.banner.src = images[i];
    document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = cap[i];
    document.getElementById("captiontitle").innerHTML = captitle[i];


    function transition(){
      document.banner.src = images[i];
      document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = cap[i];
      document.getElementById("captiontitle").innerHTML = captitle[i];
      if(i < images.length - 1){
        i = i + 1;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
      stopslideshow = setTimeout("transition()", time);
    }

    function stoptransition(){
      clearTimeout(stopslideshow);
      document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
    }

    function nextphoto(){
      if(i < images.length - 1){
        i = i + 1;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      document.banner.src = images[i];
      document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = cap[i];
      document.getElementById("captiontitle").innerHTML = captitle[i];
      document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
      clearTimeout(stopslideshow);
    }

    function previousphoto(){
      i = i - 1;
      if(i < 0){
        i = images.length - 1;
      }
      document.banner.src = images[i];
      document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = cap[i];
      document.getElementById("captiontitle").innerHTML = captitle[i];
      document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
      clearTimeout(stopslideshow);
    }

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

So now that you've read my code, let me address my problem with the slideshow.

The next/previous buttons work just fine when the page loads for the first time. However, the problem happens when I press the next/previous buttons AFTER I press the Start button.

So for some reason, when I press the start button, the next slide, which is supposed to be images[1], cap[1], and captitle[1], does not come up immediately. It starts at images[0], cap[0], and captitle[0]. The funny thing, though, is that my variable i is INCREASING/DECREASING properly based on the buttons I press, but the image does not increase/decrease as I wish it to.

And that's why I included this bit in my code at the top:

```html
<p id="firsti"></p>
<p id="ivalue"></p>
<p id="timevalue"></p>
```

I included that bit to try and find out why the images were being sorta wonky. So basically, when I press the Start button, the i value also shows. The variable i would show up as "1" when I pressed the Start button, but the images, captions, and caption title would not change. It would remain at images[0], title[0], and captitle[0].

Another strange problem, like I said above, is the next/previous buttons after I press the Start/Stop buttons. When I press the next button, the display skips a slide ahead instead of going to the next one, and for the previous button, it goes back one more slide than what I would've liked.

And finally, another bug I have is that when I press the Start multiple times, the function runs repeats as many times as I press it, and it skips slides rapidly. I don't know how to make the start function work only once. I've tried many things, but none of them have worked.

It's very long and I'm sorry, but I'm honestly stuck and I'm so close to being finished with this slideshow assignment, but I got stuck with a couple of bugs.

Help is appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:** Someone asked for my CSS so I put it here:

```css
img {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
}

#captiontitle {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#caption {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Post your css that I can run your exemple

Comment: I edited my post and put the CSS code at the very bottom. I think it is self-explanatory even without the CSS though.. because you can clearly see that when you press the next/previous buttons after you press the start button, they skip/go back a slide one more than what I want. But I still put the CSS in anyway

Comment: Try and limit yourself to one question at a time. You can only have one accepted answer. If your solution is spread over two separate answers you cannot fully give credit where credit is due.

Comment: One thing I have time to help you with is you probably would want setInterval rather than `setTimeout("transition()", time);` and also it should be `setInterval(transition, time);`  notice the `transition` without quotes and parenthesis otherwise you call the function rather then tell setInterval/timeout that is the function you want called. Also you should call setInterval in its own function, so you will have to change the Start buttons onclick to a new function (and remove setTimeout from transition() ) that uses the setInterval. This helps with some of the weird on start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep consistent when you increment your counter and set the images. With your `transition` method, you are setting the images then incrementing. With the `next` and `previous` you are incrementing and setting. So you are going to get the skip.

You should also stop the transition **before** stepping forward or back manually.

Use a variable to hold the state of the transition and use that to determine if the transition should start. I've used `transitionStarted` below. You'll note that now there is a method to explicitly start the transition and one to actually run the transition.

If also optimised your code by using an array of objects using JSON notation and reducing repetitive code. This will give you a good step into basic objects.

```js
var i = 0;
var time = 1000;
var banner = document.banner;
var imageTitle = document.getElementById("captiontitle");
var imageCaption = document.getElementById("caption");
var slideShowInterval;
var transitionStarted = false;
var imageObj = [{
    "src": "https://www.fillmurray.com/800/400",
    "title": "Title 0",
    "Description": "Description 0"
  },
  {
    "src": "http://www.placecage.com/800/400",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "Description": "Description 1"
  },
  {
    "src": "http://www.placecage.com/g/800/400",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "Description": "Description 2"
  },
  {
    "src": "http://www.placecage.com/c/800/400",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "Description": "Description 3"
  },
  {
    "src": "http://www.placecage.com/gif/800/400",
    "title": "Title 4",
    "Description": "Description 4"
  },
  {
    "src": "https://www.fillmurray.com/g/800/400",
    "title": "Title 5",
    "Description": "Description 5"
  }
];


setImage(imageObj[i]);

function setImage(imageObject) {
  banner.src = imageObject.src;
  imageTitle.innerHTML = imageObject.title;
  imageCaption.innerHTML = imageObject.Description;
}


function startTransition()
{
  if(!transitionStarted){
    transition();
    transitionStarted = true;  
  }
}

function transition() {
  if (i < imageObj.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  setImage(imageObj[i]);
  document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
  slideShowInterval = setTimeout("transition()", time);
}

function stoptransition() {
  clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
  document.getElementById("ivalue").innerHTML = i;
  transitionStarted = false;
}

function nextphoto() {
  stoptransition();
  if (i < imageObj.length - 1) {
    i = i + 1;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  setImage(imageObj[i]);
}

function previousphoto() {
  stoptransition();
  i = i - 1;
  if (i < 0) {
    i = imageObj.length - 1;
  }
  setImage(imageObj[i]);
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
}

#captiontitle {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#caption {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Slideshow</h1>
<h3 align="center">(Please note that the time transition between slides is one second. Thank you!)</h3>

<img name="banner" width="800" height="400" class="center">
<h1 id="captiontitle" align="center"></h1>
<figcaption id="caption" align="center"></figcaption>

<button id="start" onclick="startTransition()">Start</button>
<button id="stop" onclick="stoptransition()">Stop</button>
<button id="next" onclick="nextphoto()">Next Photo</button>
<button id="previous" onclick="previousphoto()">Previous Photo</button>

<p id="firsti"></p>
<p id="ivalue"></p>
<p id="timevalue"></p>
```